# Cannot change some elements style following scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone please help me to fix what I'm doing wrong here? I just want the styles to be applied to the divs after scrolling down from the top. Funny enough only the header-wrap id changes, but nothing else changes. Why is this? e.g. t1, slogan and navmenus don't change following scrolling, but header-wrap does.

Would really appreciate any help here. Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap');
    var t1 = $('#t1');
    var slogan = $('#slogan');
    var navMenu = $('ul.nav-menu');
    var navMenuLink = $('ul.nav-menu a:link');
    var navMenuVisited = $('ul.nav-menu a:visited');
    var navMenuHover = $('ul.nav-menu a:hover');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        headerWrap.addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
        t1.addClass('t1-on-scroll');
        slogan.addClass('slogan-on-scroll');
        navMenu.addClass('ul.nav-menu');
        navMenuLink.addClass('ul.nav-menu a:link');
        navMenuVisited.addClass('ul.nav-menu a:visited');
        navMenuHover.addClass('ul.nav-menu a:hover');

        if($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
            headerWrap.removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
            t1.removeClass('t1-on-scroll');
            slogan.removeClass('slogan-on-scroll');
            navMenu.removeClass('ul.nav-menu-on-scroll');
            navMenuLink.removeClass('ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:link');
            navMenuVisited.removeClass('ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:visited');
            navMenuHover.removeClass('ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:hover');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{height:1000px;width:auto;}

#header-wrap{
 background:#4E6273;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f4fafe;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;/* may not be needed but no harm in having */
 z-index:100000;
 /* margin:0 auto; needed? */
 opacity:0.9;
}
.scroll-opacity-change{
 opacity:0.9;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
 background:#f4fafe !important;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #94C8F2 !important;
}
#t1{
 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
 text-transform:none;
 color:#E6E8EB;
 font-size:24px;
}
#t1.t1-on-scroll{
 color:#f00;
}
#slogan{
 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size:12px;
 color:#E6E8EB;
}
#slogan.slogan-on-scroll{
 color:#f00;
}
ul.nav-menu{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#E6E8EB;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:50px;
}
ul.nav-menu a:link{
 color:#E6E8EB;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu a:visited{
 color:#E6E8EB;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu a:hover{
 color:#B4E9FF;
}
ul.nav-menu-on-scroll{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#f0f;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu-on-scroll li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:50px;
}
ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:link{
 color:#f0f;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:visited{
 color:#f0f;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:hover{
 color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<header id="header-wrap">
  <div id="header-top">
    <div id="header-left-wrap">
     
      <div id="header-text-wrap">
      
      <div id="header-title-wrap">
      <span id="t1">title<span id="t1-emphasis">acronym</span></span>
      </div>
      
      <div id="header-slogan-wrap">
      <span id="slogan">slogan</span>
      </div>
    
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="header-right-wrap">
    <nav class="wrap">
   <a href="#" id="header-nav-menu"></a>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery library before your javascript functions that utilize jquery? Did you put those functions in document ready? (in the snippet, jquery is not defined)

Comment: I have now, but only the first element 'header-wrap' is changing and the others aren't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is totally wrong!! You added the wrong classes to your nav-menus, and some of your code doesn't even make sense like `addClass('ul.nav-menu a:link')`or `var navMenuVisited = $('ul.nav-menu a:visited');`

```
navMenu.addClass('nav-menu-on-scroll');
...
navMenu.removeClass('nav-menu-on-scroll');
```

is all you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap');
    var t1 = $('#t1');
    var slogan = $('#slogan');
    var navMenu = $('ul.nav-menu');


    $(window).scroll(function () {
        headerWrap.addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
        t1.addClass('t1-on-scroll');
        slogan.addClass('slogan-on-scroll');
        navMenu.addClass('nav-menu-on-scroll');


        if($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
            headerWrap.removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
            t1.removeClass('t1-on-scroll');
            slogan.removeClass('slogan-on-scroll');
            navMenu.removeClass('nav-menu-on-scroll');

        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{height:1000px;width:auto;}

#header-wrap{
 background:#4E6273;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f4fafe;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;/* may not be needed but no harm in having */
 z-index:100000;
 /* margin:0 auto; needed? */
 opacity:0.9;
}
.scroll-opacity-change{
 opacity:0.9;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
 background:#f4fafe !important;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #94C8F2 !important;
}
#t1{
 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
 text-transform:none;
 color:#E6E8EB;
 font-size:24px;
}
#t1.t1-on-scroll{
 color:#f00;
}
#slogan{
 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size:12px;
 color:#E6E8EB;
}
#slogan.slogan-on-scroll{
 color:#f00;
}
ul.nav-menu{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#E6E8EB;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:50px;
}
ul.nav-menu a:link{
 color:#E6E8EB;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu a:visited{
 color:#E6E8EB;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu a:hover{
 color:#B4E9FF;
}
ul.nav-menu-on-scroll{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:400;
 color:#f0f;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu-on-scroll li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:50px;
}
ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:link{
 color:#f0f;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:visited{
 color:#f0f;
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:hover{
 color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<header id="header-wrap">
  <div id="header-top">
    <div id="header-left-wrap">
     
      <div id="header-text-wrap">
      
      <div id="header-title-wrap">
      <span id="t1">title<span id="t1-emphasis">acronym</span></span>
      </div>
      
      <div id="header-slogan-wrap">
      <span id="slogan">slogan</span>
      </div>
    
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="header-right-wrap">
    <nav class="wrap">
   <a href="#" id="header-nav-menu"></a>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: thank you very much! I assume var navMenuLink = $('ul.nav-menu a:link');, hover and visited must have been the only wrong sections since most of the other parts were similar to your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the jQuery library first, then your Javascript code must be in a function that ensures both jQuery and the document are present. Easiest way:

```
(function ready() {
  if (!document.body || !window.$) {setTimeout(ready, 50); return;}
  // Your Javascript code here
})();
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand. Can you show it in the example code?

Comment: Setting a timeout for something as trivial as making sure the jQuery library is loaded first is a bad practice and leads to performance issues with things that need to be executed on document ready.

Comment: @user3760941. Put your javascript code in the Commented line, inside the function.

Comment: So you downvoted my answer because I pointed out what you're suggesting is bad practice? 
First of all, you will never know whether the document is actually ready after 50ms. Document ready, in jQuery, will execute when the document is ready. It might take 2ms, it might take 200. It won't execute after a set time which is precisely what setTimeout does - execute after specific amount of lapsed time.

Comment: @JavierRey, sorry, I wasn't paying close enough attention - didn't notice what you're calling in setTimeout is actually the function itself, I now see you're calling the function over and over again in setTimeout and that it'll keep executing until the condition is true. I do still, however, believe that using the document ready is the proper way as it's standard, everyone understands it immediately they see it and doesn't lead to ambiguity.

Comment: No worries. Your answer is not bad (I removed the downvote), but the error in the question is not the document, but JQuery missing. Assuming the library is loaded somewhere, my function just ensures the code is executed when Jquery is available.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm guessing your problem is, that you didn't wrap your code in document ready.
Your JS code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap');
    var t1 = $('#t1');
    var slogan = $('#slogan');
    var navMenu = $('ul.nav-menu');
    var navMenuLink = $('ul.nav-menu a:link');
    var navMenuVisited = $('ul.nav-menu a:visited');
    var navMenuHover = $('ul.nav-menu a:hover');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        headerWrap.addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
        t1.addClass('t1-on-scroll');
        slogan.addClass('slogan-on-scroll');
        navMenu.addClass('ul.nav-menu');
        navMenuLink.addClass('ul.nav-menu a:link');
        navMenuVisited.addClass('ul.nav-menu a:visited');
        navMenuHover.addClass('ul.nav-menu a:hover');

        if($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
            headerWrap.removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
            t1.removeClass('t1-on-scroll');
            slogan.removeClass('slogan-on-scroll');
            navMenu.removeClass('ul.nav-menu-on-scroll');
            navMenuLink.removeClass('ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:link');
            navMenuVisited.removeClass('ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:visited');
            navMenuHover.removeClass('ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:hover');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, however I've edited the post with the javascript code and still no change. Any ideas? Also do jQuery functions require being wrapped in the document ready text in order to work?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console? If you're using Chrome, open it up with F12.
Yes, the jQuery functions should be wrapped in document ready to ensure everything works. Otherwise, to simplify a bit, you could be trying to grab an element (eg. $('.foobar')) and that element, in this case an element with class foobar is not yet loaded in the browser. Using the document ready, you ensure all of the page content is ready to be manipulated with via JS.

Comment: Yes if I use safari I get this error:
{  "message": "Script error.",  "filename": "",  "lineno": 0,  "colno": 0}
If I use chrome I get this error:
{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 134,
  "colno": 9
}
Oh I see - that may explain why some other functions of mine didn't work

Comment: Well then that's your answer, $ (symbol for jQuery, meaning jQuery) is not defined. You have to include a reference to jQuery script before you try and use jQuery. So your <head> should first have a <script src="scripts/jquery.js"> and below that you should have a <script> inside of which should be your jQuery functions (in case of inline scripting) or a reference to your .js file where you use the jQuery functions. So first script with jQuery, then your own scripts

Comment: thanks! I've edited my post to include the jQuery library, and now if you run the example I built, some of the code works. However, for some reason only #header-wrap is being edited but none of the other elements are. Why are the other elements (such as t1, slogan & nav menu) not changing?

Comment: All your classes are being changed. Your CSS is not specific enough and that's why you don't see changes, visually, for all of them. IDs are more specific than class names. Instead of having your CSS for changed state like you currently have (eg. CSS selector being .t1-on-scroll), change them to include ID (in this case #t1.t1-on-scroll) and it'll work. Also the classes like ul.nav-menu-on-scroll a:link should be different. Don't include pseudo states when you're manipulating class name. Instead of adding all that class to, in this case, navMenuLink, just add nav-menu-link-scroll & style that

Comment: your suggestion worked for all but I did not know how to implement it for the nav menu that includes pseudo elements. What code do I have to write for the nav menu links? Also, it's great that your suggestion worked but I don't understand it - for example .t1-on-scroll fails but #t1.t1-on-scroll works as CSS - but why would .scroll-opacity-change work since it doesn't have a #? it was the same format as .t1-on-scroll which fails

Comment: '.' in front of a selector (eg .scroll-opacity-change) means you're selecting a class, '#' is an ID selector. When overriding CSS properties, it basically falls down to specificity of a selector. ID has a higher specificity than class. Therefore, you can't override it (without using !important) just by specifying a single class in selector. Google 'CSS selector specificity' and I'm sure you'll find more in-depth answers to most of your questions ;)
For ul links, add class to ul (when scrolling) and then style all ul anchor children with pseudo classes. Much better performance wise as well.